# Single R commands

Tags: r

I am quite new to R and I am trying to create a single R command to execute the command in line 2. Can anyone help me how to insert the data to line 2? Thanks

```
h<- c(7.5,6.9,0.06,0.006,12,2.7,17,8,0.8,6.9)

sqrt (abs(h-mean (h)))
```

Comment: Are you asking how to run a command?  If you're in RStudio, you could just type those lines into the interactive R window

Comment: Highlight the code and press Ctrl + Enter

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function:

```
abs_sqrt <- function(x) {
    sqrt (abs(x - mean(x)))
}
```